# Change default learning rate in SpaCy's Optimizer

Tags: python, spacy

If I want to change the `learn_rate` for the optimizer, what's the correct way of doing it?

From the definition of [begin_training](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/7634812172872090fbf23d2b9adb9478fbd97770/spacy/language.py#L533) and the [default optimizer](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/c23e234d657188d6edd979028bb46d88b2eeddb6/spacy/_ml.py#L49) I am guessing I have to provide a `component_cfg param`, like this

```
optimizer = nlp.begin_training(component_cfg={'learn_rate': 0.01})?
```

But I do not know if its the correct way, because if I call `begin_training` like this

```
optimizer = nlp.begin_training(component_cfg={'dummy_param': 0.01})?
```

No warning or error is given.

Answer (score 4):

To change the spaCy default settings, you need to overwrite the default parameters value.

In your case, to change the learning rate you can do the following:

```
optimizer.learn_rate = 0.01
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this is the "correct" answer, but this worked for me (so it's more like a note to self :p):

- I didn't use `begin_training()` to return an optimizer, because it
  would just create a default one. I *think* that you might trick it
  with environment variables, but I haven't tried
- instead, I ended up spawning my own optimizer. So my code looks like this:

```
from thinc.neural.optimizers import Adam
from thinc.neural import Model

# .... other bits of code :)

nlp.begin_training()

# optimizer options. Defaults are changed where commented
ops = Model.ops
learn_rate = 0.001
beta1 = 0.9
beta2 = 0.999
eps = 1e-8
L2 = 1e-6
max_grad_norm = 1.0
optimizer = Adam(ops, learn_rate, L2=L2, beta1=beta1, beta2=beta2, eps=eps)
optimizer.max_grad_norm = max_grad_norm
optimizer.device = ops.device
```

As you might have guessed, most of the above was copy-pasted from the code which generates the default optimizer in the first place: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/69e70ffae16700e990d60640f27eb7f980c0ba50/spacy/_ml.py#L49

Which seems to be called from the `begin_training()` method here: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/4d4b3b0783bdca38493e27dee2939b3ded735c4e/spacy/language.py#L597 Which is where I got the idea that `ops` should be `thinc.neural.Model.ops`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the optimizer creation at https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/69e70ffae16700e990d60640f27eb7f980c0ba50/spacy/_ml.py#L49, spacy picks up values for learn_rate, beta1, beta2 etc. from environment variables. You can always start your script with

```
learn_rate=0.005 python script.py
```

for spacy to use a learning rate of 0.005 and so on.

Reference: https://spacy.io/api/cli#train-hyperparams